# Sobrecarga de método em C#

Tags: c#, .net, método, sobrecarga

Estou aprendendo sobre sobrecarga de métodos em C# e gostaria de criar um programa simples que leia idade e nome de um usuário, porém gostaria de criar dois métodos com o mesmo nome (sobrecarga) onde dependendo se o usuário digitou sua idade ou não, irá mostrar a idade (se digitado) ou uma mensagem caso não tenha sido digitado nada (quero que fazer com que a idade seja inserida de forma opcional pelo usuário).

Criei este pequeno código, porém não está funcionando:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string numero; string letra,resultado;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma letra: (opcional)");
            letra = Console.ReadLine();
            resultado = MostraNaTela(numero, letra);
            Console.WriteLine("O resultado é");
        }
        public static void MostraNaTela(string num) 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("O numero é {0}",num, "Não foi preenchido letra");

        }
        public static void MostraNaTela(string num2, string letr2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num2);
            Console.WriteLine(letr2);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema na verdade não tem a ver com sobrecarga, tem com o uso do método. Na verdade eu não sei se o método está errado ou o uso, porque conceitualmente este método não deveria ser usado assim por mais de uma razão.

Eu melhorei o código porque ele tem vários problemas, alguns não graves e alguns é só porque é um jeito antigo de se programar ou deixar mais legível. Não resolvi todos problemas, porque nem faz muito sentido fazer um código assim.

O principal problema é tentar guardar um resultado em um método que retorna nada. É só olhar o erro que o compilador dá que ele mostra isso. Nem faria sentido retornar algo em um método que o nome indica que vai apenas mostrar algo. Então tive que mudar a ordem para tentar fazer sentido. Mas toda ideia parece errada, repense isso e se preocupe primeiro com questões mais básicas do código para depois que dominar essa parte partir para sobrecarga que é um conceito mais avançado e nem parece fazer sentido nesse caso.

Veja todos detalhes que eu mudei.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Digite um numero: ");
        var numero = ReadLine();
        WriteLine("Digite uma letra: (opcional)");
        var letra = ReadLine();
        WriteLine("O resultado é");
        MostraNaTela(numero, letra);
    }
    public static void MostraNaTela(string num) => WriteLine($"O numero é {num} Não foi preenchido letra");

    public static void MostraNaTela(string numero, string letra) {
        WriteLine(numero);
        WriteLine(letra);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6cx3oN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/82tyl7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnVoid.cs).